# Проблема с анимацией печати текста для первой надписи

Tags: css, reactjs, веб-программирование, jsx

Всем привет, я сделал анимацию печати слоганов и чередование их, но заметил проблему, что как только страница загрузилась или перезагрузилась, первый слоган не печатается, а просто появляется, далее все нормально. Думаю мб виновато состояние `isTyping` или анимация не успевает прогрузиться? Заранее спасибо

```js
const { StrictMode, useState, useEffect } = React
const { render } = ReactDOM

const slogans = [
  "свобода чего-то",
  "Как и этот",
  "Верстка",
  "Программирование",
  "Что-то еще",
];

const RegistrationForms = () => {
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);
  const [WhichForm, setWhichForm] = useState(true);
  const [sloganIndex, setSloganIndex] = useState(0);

  const toggleForm = (isLogin) => {
    setShowForm(true);
    setWhichForm(isLogin);
  };
  
  const [isTyping, setIsTyping] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const changeSloganInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setSloganIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % slogans.length); // Переключаю между 0 и 1
    }, 5000); // Интервал смены слоганов

    return () => {
      clearInterval(changeSloganInterval);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsTyping(true);
    const typingTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsTyping(false);
    }, 3000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(typingTimeout);
    };
  }, [sloganIndex]);

  return (
    <div className="registration-form">

      <div className="Logo">
        <img src="/logo/KeyWML.svg" alt="Логотип" />
      </div>

      <div className="Slogan">
        <div className="FixedText">Слоган:</div>
          <div className="ChangingText">
            {isTyping ? (
              slogans[sloganIndex].split('').map((char, charIndex) => (
                <span
                  key={charIndex}
                  style={{ animation: `typing ${0.1 + (charIndex * 0.1)}s step-end` }}
                >
                  {char === ' ' ? '\u00A0' : char} {}
                </span>
              ))
            ) : (
              slogans[sloganIndex]
            )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  )
}

render(
  <StrictMode>
    <RegistrationForms />
  </StrictMode>,
  document.querySelector("main")
);
```

```css
.ChangingText {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  animation: blink-caret 0.75s step-end infinite, typing 3s steps(30, end), printed-text 5s ease;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.ChangingText span {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<main></main>
```

Comment: Не "спacиδо" надо добавлять, а запускаемый сниппет.

Comment: Проблема в `animation: typing 3s steps(30, end)` на `ChangingText`. Блок честно три секунды скрыт перед тем как показаться

Comment: Нет, это абсолютно не повлияло